# how can i make a username and password test method that doesnt overlap?

Tags: java, string

I need to make a class where if the user inputs the username "alex" with the password "mightyducks" or the username "emily" with the password "cat", they are logged into the system
Here's my code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Usernames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type your username:");
        String user = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Type your password:");
        String pass = reader.nextLine();

        if (pass.equals("mightyducks")&& user.equals("alex")) {
            System.out.println("You are now logged into the system!"); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your username or password was invalid!");
        }   
        if (user.equals("emily") && pass.equals("cat")) {
            System.out.println("You are now logged into the system!");
        } else {
         System.out.println("Your username or password was invalid!");
        }
    }
}
```

My desired output when I enter either "alex + mightyducks" or "emily + cat" is "You are now logged into the system!"
But my actual output is:
"You are now logged into the system!"
"Your username or password was invalid!"
How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because once you authorize the user in the first `if` statement, you fall through and test the second `if` statement. Similarly, if you were to put in invalid credentials, you would get the error message twice (once for the first if/else block and again for the second if/else block).

Try simplifying it a bit:

```
if (pass.equals("mightyducks") && user.equals("alex")) {
    System.out.println("You are now logged into the system!"); 
} else if (user.equals("emily") && pass.equals("cat")) {
    System.out.println("You are now logged into the system!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Your username or password was invalid!");
}
```

There are ways to make that a bit simpler by collapsing the first two tests, but I wanted to keep it this way to illustrate how the if/else parts work.

Answer (score 0):

No need to make more if else block .as Java provide else if. below code can work for you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Match_Name_Pass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
       Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the user name : ");
       String username = scn.next();
       System.out.println("Enter the password");
       String password = scn.next();

       if(username.equals("alex")  && password.equals("mightyducks") )
        {
        System.out.println("You are now logged into the system!");
        }
       else if(username.equals("emily") && password.equals("cat"))
        {
        System.out.println("You are now logged into the system!");
        }
       else
       {
        System.out.println("Your username or password was invalid!");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `Map` instead and get rid of `multiple if-else` blocks:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Ideone {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map <String, String> map = new HashMap <String, String> ();
    map.put("alex", "mightyducks");
    map.put("emily", "cat");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type your username:");
    String user = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Type your password:");
    String pass = reader.nextLine();
    reader.close();
    if (null != map.get(user) && map.get(user).equals(pass)) {
      System.out.println("You are now logged into the system!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Your username or password was invalid!");
    }
  }
}
```

Sample [code works here](https://ideone.com/SowxBV)